# Why prefer the indirect generic's import to the actual class?

Tags: java, generics, compiler-errors

Using eclipse if I write this interface in the package `mypack`:

```
package mypack;
public interface MyInterface<A>{
  public interface Test{
    void sayHi();
  }
}
```

And if I write this class in **no** package.

```
public class Test implements mypack.MyInterface<mypack.MyInterface.Test> {
  private Test test = new Test();
}
```

Eclipse trigger me an error at compile-time, that I must implement the method `sayHi()`.

I see no way out!

If I <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>LMB</kbd> to the type of the field `test` it takes me to the Class.

### Bug reported

A small bug is reported here: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=488077

Comment: How does one extend an interface in a concrete class?

Comment: I don't see why you would have to implement `sayHi`

Comment: @PeterLawrey Me neither :D try it yourself

Comment: I assume `MyInteface` should be `MyInterface`.  I suggest you post the code you are actually having trouble with as you are likely to leave out the key detail which is your problem.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I missed that. Why make that so confusing? Just choose a better name, and avoid the name clashes.

Comment: That is kind of the point of the question, JB :)

Comment: I understand that now. But any solution will be worse than just choosing a better, non-clashing name.

Comment: Took me a minute to spot that too. I'm with @JBNizet. Sometimes it's not a creative, out of the box solution you want. It's the common sense solution staring you in the face.

Comment: That said, you can just use `mypack.Test test = new mypack.Test();`. Which is worse than just `MyConcreteImplementation impl = new MyConcreteImplementation();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is happening here is

```
Test test = new Test();
```

the `Test` is being taken as a nested-type of the `MyInterface` you inherit from.

I will look into the JLS to see if there is a reason it chooses the inherited class over it's own name.

Note: `MyInterface` doesn't have to be generic. A simpler form of this problem is

```
interface MyInterface {
    interface Test {
    }
}

class Test extends MyInterface {
    Test test = new Test(); // thinks this is the MyInterface.Test
}
```

BTW: As this is very confusion combination of class structure and names, I suggest you never do this in reality.

A note from [JLS 7.4.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-7.html)

> Unnamed packages are provided by the Java SE platform principally for convenience when developing small or temporary applications or when just beginning development.

Comment: I am not the one who tries to test around until i found a good question i could ask at stackoverflow. All my questions came from reality, from working(sometimes) and existing code i am not allowed to offer to the public.

Comment: This doesn't have to do with the default package. Everything is in the mypack package.

Comment: @JBNizet Not in the question, but you are right that it doesn't matter in this case.

Comment: You're right. I missed the "no package" in the question. Something else that should absolutely be avoided.

Comment: @JBNizet i disagree again, if `Test` is in the package `mypack`, i could write  `mypack.Test test = new mypack.Test()` without errors. In default package i can not specify the package!

Comment: Yes, I know that. I even wrote it as a comment under your question. As I said: I missed the "no package" in the question. But again, the solution is dead simple: don't put any class, ever, in the default package. Doing that is bad practice, and leads to all kinds of problems (including the one you're facing). Everything goes smoother when avoiding bad practices: they're bad practices for good reasons.

Comment: @PeterRader I suspect this is an outright bug.  This means that when they added nested classes it breaks backward compatibility. The simple solution is don't re-use names like this its generally confusing, not just to the compiler.

Comment: @PeterRader If it's not meant to be an nested interface in the question, I suggest you update your question.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Ah, ok, i see. The more specifity to the interface cames via the implementation of MyInterface<A>.

Comment: So there is a bug in eclipse because if I <kbd>Ctrl<kbd><kbd>LMB</kbd> to the `new Test()` it leads me to the Class, not the Interface. I will report a bug for it! I was confused what you mean with `sub-type`, in my pov a sub-type is not a nested type.